# Book that summarizes mathematics in a way appropriate for preservation for future generations

Tags: soft-question, reference-request

Maybe this question is a bit silly, but I'll take that risk and ask it anyway. Recently, I've been thinking about making a time capsule to be hidden in the ground and (hopefully) not be opened for at least a few centuries.

Naturally, storage space will be quite limited, and so I want to pick out items that in as good a way as possible will represent the very essence of humanity (and perhaps even be of some practical use, should society have completely broken down). To me, this is mathematical and scientific advancement.

I would therefore like to hear some suggestions for one, or possibly two, books which summarize most of mathematics at its current stage. Preferably, the book(s) should feature some proofs, but most of all it(they) should be a comprehensive collection of mathematical knowledge thus far.

I have considered something like a mathematical encyclopedia, but in my experience, the level of technicality is often quite low in these, and I want something with precise statements of mathematical results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not really sure if this fits your format, but a data-dump of Wikipedia would surely be a stamp of our days and does hold a lot of mathematics (even if in a rather chaotic manner).

Comment: @dtldarek That's a good suggestion! The only problem is, I cannot rely on digital storage of the information, so I would have to print it.

Comment: But why books? The technology, though not standard, [exists](http://www.norsam.com/business-relations.html)
to store vast amounts of text inscribed microscopically on stable media.
The main book to include in the time capsule should
therefore contain instructions to build a microscope.

Comment: @BobPego In principle, I think you may be right. However, my budget is certainly quite limited and I'm not sure I could afford to acquire microfilm or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

What about the Princeton Companion to Mathematics?

Comment: I actually didn't know about this before. I think it looks good! For the purpose I intend for it, I think its inclusion of a collection of biographies as well as an overview of mathematical history is quite appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood well your suggestion but if we have to preserve the Math for some long time, in my opinion, for sure, *The Elements*, by Euclides, must be there.

Comment: That's a good suggestion! However, storage space might be an issue, as it consists of 13 books. Admittedly, I've never actually read $\textit{The Elements}$. Is it "efficiently" written?

Comment: For me, it is *The Book* to teach and learn Geometry. But its size is not a problem. You can have all books on a small book.

Comment: The term "book" refers to how in ancient times, each part of a work would be written on a separate scroll.  So it took 13 scrolls to write Euclid's Elements.  But you can get the whole thing nowadays in one volume; check out the Green Lion edition of Euclid's Elements.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well in that case, I think $\textit{The Elements}$ seems like an excellent work to include. The Green Lion edition (as sold on amazon) is rather cheap too, which is a factor of nontrivial importance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that you want something encyclopedic, but if you really want to capture the spirit of mathematics, it's hard to do better than this poem by mathematician par excellence William Rowan Hamilton, concerning his discovery of quaternions (which eventually lead to vectors, matrices, tensors, linear algebra, differential geometry, Lie group theory, etc.):

THE TETRACTYS

Or high Mathesis, with her charm severe,

Of line and number, was our theme; and we

Sought to behold her unborn progeny,

And thrones reserved in Truth's celestial sphere:

While views, before attained, became more clear;

And how the One of Time, of Space the Three,

Might, in the Chain of Symbol, girdled be:

And when my eager and reverted ear

Caught some faint echoes of an ancient strain,

Some shadowy outlines of old thoughts sublime,

Gently he smiled to see, revived again,

In later age, and occidental clime,

A dimly traced Pythagorean lore,

A westward floating, mystic dream of FOUR.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! It would of course be possible to include a few selected items on mathematics apart from the book itself, and something like this could be a candidate.